# Can someone with a Kobo e-reader test if Wikilinks work when viewing Wikipedia on Pocket or its browser?

Tags: ereader, wikipedia

I'm looking for an e-reader to read Wikipedia, ideally that is not very costly, is relatively repairable, and is run by a company with some environmental ethos ([here's my original question about that](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18261/what-e-reader-is-good-for-browsing-wikipedia-and-navigating-its-wiki-links/)). It looks like Boox and Kobo are the best options, but Boox is notoriously un-repairable and its maker has had questionable ethics on a few things.

Kobo seems like a good option and is also more affordable. However, I can't get an answer to this:

##### When you open a Wikipedia page, either via Pocket or its web browser, do Wikilinks work? Can you click a Wikilink and view the next Wikipedia page with no problems?

If anyone could test and confirm, that would be much appreciated and is not answered anywhere else! Does Pocket app on Kobo series of e-readers let you go from one Wikipedia article to the next without problems?

Comment: Hi cr0, sorry but this question is off-topic since it's about how a specific device works, rather than about procuring new hardware. You might want to try Superuser; I'd love to just answer the question directly in the comments, but I don't own a Kobo so I can't test it myself :/

Comment: Actually let me see if I can auto-migrate this, bear with me for a second...

Comment: @JMY1000 This kind of devices are off-topic at SU.

Comment: What makes this off topic on Super User? There’s a whole ereader tag

Comment: Because you are asking if an e-reader works with a specific website. This is not a debugging or “having an issue” with an e-reader question. It does not fit on any SE site. It is better suited for a conversational site like Reddit; not a question and answer format like Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Also, it is fairly ridiculous to ask if ONE website works with ONE reader device. It is personal preference you are talking about and not technical limitations.

Comment: It is a technical question and a simple thing to test, providing info I can't find elsewhere. This isn't one random blog I'm asking about. Wikipedia is widely used and Wikilinks are a distinct feature. Does Pocket app on Kobo series of e-readers let you go from one Wikipedia article to the next? I hope someone with one of these devices can do this simple test, as I haven't been able to find that info otherwise.

Comment: I'm with cr0 on this one; we've already worked to address what devices might work well for Wikipedia over on the Hardware Recs SE, and this was a pertinent technical question. The Kobo line is quite popular (this isn't some obscure one-off device), and "reading Wikipedia" is a pretty good and normal use case for an ereader—there's a reason Kindles allow you to use Wikipedia (and only Wikipedia) with their free data. Given that you can't just load another browser onto a Kobo, whether the builtin apps properly support Wikipedia seems pretty important. That's a clear technical question.

Comment: I'd go to a store where they have a kobo reader in display and try it out by myself if what I need is working correctly. For me it would be worth paying a small premium over ordering the reader online.

Comment: @1NN I would do the same, but I cannot find stores near me that carry Kobo devices. Walmart is the vendor in the USA but none seem to have them for pickup, they all get ordered to the store. I'm surprised no one with one of these devices will make a simple test of this, given how popular both Kobo and its Pocket feature seems to be.

Comment: @cr0 See my edited answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT

1. **Warning about Wikipedia in pocket**: Page-Internal links will mostly not work inside the pocket-app. Even if you try to "sync to pocket", they do not work correctly. So, **the whole page-internal menu structure of a Wikipedia article simply will not work !** Also, pocket will completely edit out any table lines. And large tables cannot be scrolled horizontally, so they just are mainly outside of the visible page (this can be tested on any smartphone) Also, all sections of the page will be opened up, and you can't close them to quickly skip to the next section.
   ***Reading Wikipedia from within pocket is a terrible user experience ! Test it out on a smartphone or tablet before buying any device specifically for this !***
2. Test on a Kobo ereader.

I have successfully tested this on a **Kobo 'Aura H20 Edition 2'** ereader, and can confirm that in principle and within the limits explained above, it works as expected:

- the **Pocket App** will navigate between pages which were previously saved on your account. If you press a link to a non-saved page, the app will ask you whether to open it in a browser or to sync it to pocket. The good thing is that navigation works the same way as in books, in a paged experience (no scrolling). However, I experienced some issues syncing freshly saved contents to the ereader, but this could be due to the pocket-account present on the ereader, which I was not allowed to change.
- The **browser** can be found under beta-features, and it works just as a normal bare-bone browser without any whistles or bells. There's a dedicated 'save to pocket' button next to the address bar, which can be handy. Browsing webpages is not a pleasant experience as the scrolling causes horrible ghosting, and therefore needs a lot of patience. Also, due to the B/W screen, some contents can be hard to read as they may lack contrast.

### Old Answer

[This video](https://youtu.be/ngeBq1VSTD8?si=hTYE1sjTsTtIN0oe) from 6 years ago shows that browsing works as expected on a Kobo, so this should partially answer your question: you'll be able to read wikipedia in the kobo browser. Though note that the kobo browser, after 6 years, [officially is still in beta](https://help.kobo.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017763733-About-Beta-Features).

Although I have not tested this (yet) on a Kobo, I can confirm that you can read the whole Wikipedia from within pocket. Long-click on any link and choose 'save in pocket'. The linked article will immediately sync to your pocket library, and from then on the app will automatically open the pocket-version of that page. Since Pocket is available since many years on Kobo, I would suppose this will work also on a Kobo device, as long as you're connected to the Internet.
(I can't test this right now on a Kobo device, but I might have a chance to do it in the next 10 days, and would then update this answer. )

Furthermore, I'd recommend you to [read through this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/kobo/comments/twfbr0/looking_for_a_cheap_eink_device_primarily_to_read/), where the OP has a very similar question to yours. Just to cite one answer from there (which reflects my experience):

> If Wikipedia is really the thing you wanna do on the device, I'd recommend getting an e-ink device that is powered by Android on the backend and can load apps from the Play Store (or at least sideload them somehow). My personal feeling is that the Android app for Wikipedia is the best way to read Wikipedia articles, and I already use a normal android tablet with it quite frequently.

(I myself have a Boox device and would not change it, simply for the fact to be able to freely run android apps).